# Map is not centered when displayed in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, osmdroid

I have an app displaying a map using OSM droid.

When I call

```
mapView.setCenter(new GeoPoint(foo,bar));
```

from the mapvies `onCreateView()` and the map is displayed in an activity containing the required `<MapView>` it centers fine.
But when that `<MapView>` is inside a fragment that then is loaded into a layout programatically, it centers with an offset that places the desired center at the upper left corner.

I have tried to call `mapView.setCenter()` in the fragment `onStart()` and `onResume()` as well but still the same issue.

What could be the issue, and the solution?

Comment: Which version of osmdroid are you using?

Comment: @MKer I'm using the precompiled 4.2 libraries. No Maven.

Comment: 4.2 is the issue. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28742551/3151518

Comment: Thanks @MKer. I will try this and get back. As of today I skipped the automatic centering since that really was not the functionality I needed. But I must say, since working with OSMDroid in two projects I'm a bit put down by how buggy and undocumented the framework is in more places than this.

Comment: Undocumented, I fully agree. Buggy, I don't see. Initial centering in 4.2 has been a long standing issue, but is solved in 4.3. Most open issues in the project are really enhancement requests. And OSMBonusPack can help in many cases :-)

Comment: @MKer Fair enough that it might not be buggy. To me a lack of documentation can make things look buggy, since the intended operations are a bit shrouded.

Comment: By the way @MKer the issue is related to 4.2. Consider adding that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add next into your Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mapView.setCenter(new GeoPoint(foo,bar));
        }
    });
}
```